# Orphan stacktraces in sys._current_frames()

Tags: python, generator, stack-trace, introspection

Here's an esoteric pure-Python question.

I'm doing some statistical profiling using `sys._current_frames()`. i.e. I've got a background thread that runs `sys._current_frames()` once every second, dumps the results in a text file, and then later I've got some Python code that sorts the tracebacks from most common to least.

One curious phenomenon I've seen is tracebacks like these:

```
  File "/opt/foo/bar.py", line 1437, in __iter__
    yield key
```

This `yield` is a generator that I wrote. The curious thing is that there's just one frame on this traceback. How could this be? The other traceback have lots of frames, either from the top level of the process or the top level of the frame. What is the meaning of this single-frame stacktrace?

One theory that I had is that this is a generator's frozen state, after it's yielded a value and it's waiting to have `next` called on it again. But I think I disproved this theory with a separate experiment: I made a generator, ensured it was paused, called  `sys._current_frames()` and I didn't see that kind of stacktrace.

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help to dig into this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `sys._current_frames()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._current_frames) warns,

> This is most useful for debugging deadlock: this function does not require the deadlocked threads’ cooperation, and such threads’ call stacks are frozen for as long as they remain deadlocked. The frame returned for a non-deadlocked thread may bear no relationship to that thread’s current activity by the time calling code examines the frame.

`sys._current_frames()` is naturally prone to race conditions in any situation where you cannot guarantee the threads of interest are paused.

---

As you suspected, you're seeing a stack trace for a suspended generator. When a generator suspends, its stack frame has no parent frames. Its `f_back` is set to null.

`sys._current_frames()` retrieves stack frames for currently running threads, but by the time you look at those frames, they may not be running any more. If a generator suspends between the time you call `sys._current_frames()` and the time you inspect the frame, this is what it will look like. You might also see it on top of a call stack that looks completely different from when you actually called `sys._current_frames()`, if it gets resumed somewhere else.

Your test didn't show the generator frame because you suspended the generator before calling `sys._current_frames()` instead of afterward. The generator's stack frame was not the active frame of any thread at that point.

Comment: Interesting theory, I'll try to create an experiment to prove it.

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to reproduce it only in Python 3.5 and Python 2.7, despite the fact it originally happened for me on Python 3.6.
Here's my code for reproducing it: https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/8f5715cda9b64e0bff443a8c1109af51
You may need to run it multiple times. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This intrigued me so I modified @RamRachum 's code into https://gist.github.com/shaib/050282dc50488759760bae2c89f966d1 which produces the "empty" traces on every run. I use locks to make almost-sure there's a frame fetched from within the generator and processed only when it's suspended.